# Fluid simulation not showing for complex scenes

Tags: fluid-simulation

Good evening all, I'm experimenting quite a lot with the fluid simulation, but unfortunately it only seems to work with very easy shapes.

[image: liquid simulation]

The cube is the domain, the mountain the collision object, and the sphere on top is the water emission.

I've tried lots of difference settings, playing with the division, and pretty much everything else.

Am I missing something? I'm using 3.0 Alpha btw

Thank you

Comment: As you can see in your screenshot, the smaller cube in the bottom right corner of the domain cube is the voxel size at the domain resolution you've set. This is much too large for the small details in your landscape.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm maybe it is because your fluid resolution is too small (like if it is 64, then try 128, it will be harder for pc so choose that number wisely). You see that small cube in the edge of your domain? That's a size of particle and your sphere is smaller than that cube... Maybe you can try to make particle smaller or sphere bigger.
Not sure about it without your blender file, If you can post it as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did try to change the parameters you suggest, but doesn't seem to work. Anyway, if you want to have a look https://www.mediafire.com/file/b25xjgraeop9n9l/mountain524.blend/file

Comment: Hmmm 1st thing... your icosphere is set to outflow (that means that water is going out of scene... I presume you wanted water to come out of icosphere? If yes then you have to change it to Inflow ...
Then you need to go to cache and change Type from All to Replay... change resolution division of your domain and you are good to go... it worked in my case, let me know about yours

Comment: It did work! Thank you